# Can't find the module in pip3

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pip

I have installed packages in pip3 but can't use that package in terminal.

For example:
`pip3 install pgcli`

`% pgcli -h localhost -U name -d db`
zsh: command not found: pgcli

But pgcli do is in my pip3 list.

I am using M2 chip.

I guessed it is because command line can't find the correct path, so I tried editing zshrc file.
`export PYTHONPATH="/Users/peter/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"`, but it didn't work.

```
pip3 show pgcli
Name: pgcli
Version: 3.5.0
Summary: CLI for Postgres Database. With auto-completion and syntax highlighting.
Home-page: http://pgcli.com
Author: Pgcli Core Team
Author-email: pgcli-dev@googlegroups.com
License: BSD
Location: /Users/peter/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages
Requires: cli-helpers, click, configobj, pendulum, pgspecial, prompt-toolkit, psycopg, Pygments, setproctitle, sqlparse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package's location is at `site-packages`, but the executable is not in that location, and PYTHONPATH if for Python, not for your shell.

The fix for your zshrc:

```
path+=('/Users/peter/Library/Python/3.9/bin')
export PATH
```